# What to do with surplus thuja leaves after pruning?

Tags: pruning, compost, mulch, conifers

We all know that there are tons of thuja leaves after pruning thuja hedges.

Can thuja leaves be used as mulch (perhaps for acid-loving plants, let's say young pines, or vaccinum)? What if they are put in a compost pile?

I've read something about thujaplicin, thujone, and acetic acids as being present in thuja leaves? Are they harmful or helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty much any organic material can be used as a mulch or composted, so yes you can do that.  I personally toss stuff like that into my long term compost pile that I let break down for a few years before it is usable.  Either that or I'll just leave the clippings where they land and cover them up with a better looking mulch.  I wouldn't think too hard about specific plant constituents and their affect on compost and/or soil as that involves very complex chemical and biologic processes and I doubt it really makes much of a difference once it breaks down.